# Problem Installing High Sierra (10.13)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, high-sierra, bootable-disk

I have created bootable pen-drive using installer. I performed following Steps but it failes.

1. Erase the Hard-disk from disk utility.
2. restart the iMac (hold down - Option key)
3. it shows me the pen-drive (but i select the pendrive prohibited symbol display.)

> Note: same pen-drive works in other macs. no issue in startup one more
>   thing i cant even see my internal hard-disk as startup disk list

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us which iMac model you‘re trying to install it on? Have you confirmed it‘s compatible with High Sierra?

Comment: yes it's compatible with High Sierra. because i already installed High on that, but due to  my SSD failed i replace it with new hard-disk, after that problem is occured

Comment: i can show my hard-disk in Disk Utility, but cannot listed in when i try to install os using bootable pendrive